# what does "orange" mean in a Mozilla's hg commit message?

Tags: mercurial, mozilla, orange

In a Mozilla's hg commit message, for example, "try to back out 324397 to see if it's the cause of orange on bm-xserve08", what does "orange" mean?

Comment: Most likely some automated test report turned from green (or yellow) to orange (to indicate a problem with the test result).

Comment: To best know what this means, talk to the people using this system. This is not a common terminology used by everyone, but is status codes localized to Firefox development.

Answer (score 1):

Orange means tests failed, red means builds failed. Green means all is well. See [the treeherder help page](https://treeherder.mozilla.org/help.html).